# Retrieve the single value from webapi by using Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

Goal: retrieve the single value "test" in Angular.

Problem: I get an error message

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse ()

What syntax am I missing?

---

ASP.NET

```
// https://localhost:44353/api/Jobadvertisement/VVValidate/4
[HttpGet("VVValidate/{id:int}")]
public ActionResult<String> VVValidate(int id)
{
    return "test";
}
```

---

Angular

```
const url = environment.url

let asdfasdf2 = url + 'api/Jobadvertisement/VVValidate/' + "4";

var dsfsdssf = this.http.get(asdfasdf2).subscribe(data => {

  console.log(data);

});
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try using httpOptions in Angular with something like this:

```
const url = environment.url;
let asdfasdf2 = url + 'api/Jobadvertisement/VVValidate/' + "4"; 
var dsfsdssf = this.http.get(asdfasdf2, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `ActionResult` to `string`:

```
[HttpGet("VVValidate/{id:int}")]
public string VVValidate(int id)
{
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: What is the different to use ActionResult<String> and string?

Answer (score 1):

Angular's [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http) expects JSON data per default, which is why you get a JSON deserialization error upon returning plain text from your API.

You need to pass `responseType: 'text'` as option to the `get` method, in order to prevent `HttpClient` from treating your data as JSON:

```
httpClient.get("url", { responseType: 'text' });
```

You can find more information regarding this in [Angular's Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data).

Even though your API code works as it is, I'd like to point out two things:

1. You can unwrap your `String` and remove the `ActionResult`, as it is not needed.
2. I would encourage you to use the `string` type instead of `System.String`. For a detailed explanation, please refer to [this](https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2019/04/08/string-vs-String-is-not-about-style.html).

Your code would look like this after applying these changes:

```
[HttpGet("VVValidate/{id:int}")]
public string VVValidate(int id)
{
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: What is the different to use ActionResult<String> and string?

Comment: @What'sUP `string` only allows you to return a string, `ActionResult<string>` allows you to return a string or an ActionResult, like `NotFound()`, `InternalServerError()`, etc.